# Remove Double quotes from json_encode php

Tags: php, json

I want to remove double inverted commas from key and value

input

```
{ 
  "center" : "new google.maps.LatLng( 57.70887 , 11.974559999999997 )" , 
  "zoom":"12",
  "mapTypeId":"google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP"
}
```

Output

```
{
  center:new google.maps.LatLng( 57.70887 , 11.974559999999997 ),
  zoom:12,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

Comment: Okay. What have you tried? Why serialize to JSON in the first place if you don't actually want JSON?

Comment: I want to convert from PHP to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

well,

```
{ 
  "center" : "new google.maps.LatLng( 57.70887 , 11.974559999999997 )" , 
  "zoom":"12",
  "mapTypeId":"google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP"
}
```

is valid `json`, if you want to use this inside `javascript`(returning from `PHP`[I assume that you're making `ajax` call])
so on your success `ajax` call.

```
success: function(res){
    obj = $.parseJSON(res);
    //here you can use that obj like  obj.center, obj.zoom and obj.mapTypeId    
}
```

and if you're posting this stuff to `PHP` from `JS` then

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['your_json_data'], TRUE);
//and you can access stuff like $data['zoom'] etc...
echo $data['center'];
echo $data['zoom'];
echo $data['mapTypeId'];
```

hope this will help you